# Filter data obtained through GitHub API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, filter, github-api

I created this function to obtain GitHub issues:

```
retrieveEnerpriseIssues: function(repoOrg, repoName, callback) { 
  let data = null;

  // token auth
  octokit.authenticate({
    type: 'basic',
    username: config.githubEnterprise.username,
    password: config.githubEnterprise.token
  });

  async function paginate(method) {
    let response = await method({
      q: "repo:" + repoOrg + "/" + repoName + " is:issue",
      per_page: 100
    });
    data = response.data.items;
    var count = 0;
    while (octokit.hasNextPage(response)) {
      count++;
      console.log(`request n°${count}`);
      response = await octokit.getNextPage(response);
      data = data.concat(response.data.items);
    }
    return data;
  }

  paginate(octokit.search.issues)
    .then(data => {
      callback(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

It is called in this function which takes the issues, filters out all of the unwanted keys into json format and puts it in my db.

```
extractToDb: function() {
  let gitIssues = null;
  for(var i = 0; i < config.githubEnterprise.orgs.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < config.githubEnterprise.orgs[i].repos.length; j++) {
      gitHubService.retrieveEnerpriseIssues(
        config.githubEnterprise.orgs[i].owner,
        config.githubEnterprise.orgs[i].repos[j].repoName,
        function(data, err) {
          if(err) {
            console.log('err: ', err);
          } else {
            gitIssues = data;
          }
          gitIssues = JSON.stringify(gitIssues);
          gitIssues = JSON.parse(gitIssues);
          let issueFormatForDb = null;
          for(var i = 0; i < gitIssues.length; i++) {
            issueFormatForDb = gitIssues[i];
            const body = '{' +
              '"github_id": "' + issueFormatForDb.id + '",' +
              '"issue_title": "' + issueFormatForDb.title + '",' +
              '"issue_number": "' + issueFormatForDb.number + '",' +
              '"issue_url": "' + issueFormatForDb.url + '",' +
              '"issue_state": "' + issueFormatForDb.state + '"' +  
          '}';
          console.log('Body: ', body);
          getGitHubIssues.postToDb(body);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to take this a step further by filtering out any issues where the state is closed. How is this done and should it be handled in my `retrieveEnerpriseIssues` function or my `extractToDb`?

**Possible solution**
I tried this in my `extractToDb` function:

```
gitIssues = JSON.parse(gitIssues);
gitIssues = _.where(gitIssues, {state: "open"});
let issueFormatForDb = null;
```

Is it the best solution or is there a better way?

Comment: Better use _.filter, or native filter method like `gitIssues = gitIssues.filter(i => i.state === 'open')`, I think .where was deprecated in later versions of lodash https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Deprecations. Other than that its perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @givehug stated:

Better use _.filter, or native filter method like

```
gitIssues = gitIssues.filter(i => i.state === 'open')
```

I think .where was deprecated in later versions of lodash [github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Deprecations](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Deprecations). Other than that its perfectly fine.

I just realsied I can filter the state in my `paginate` function with this:

```
let response = await method({
    q: "repo:" + repoOrg + "/" + repoName + " is:issue" + " label:issue_label" + " state:open",
    per_page: 100
  });
```